# Android return transition doesn't work after 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, shared-element-transition

Using the AndroidX navigation component, I've created a shared element transition between two fragments. The first fragment has a RecyclerView, and the second fragment shows details of the clicked element. The enter transition always works as expected. The return transition works if I hit the back button right away. However, if I wait more than about 5 seconds before hitting the back button, the animation doesn't work properly.

In that case, there is no animation at all. No move, no fade, everything in the fragment just shows up immediately in place.

Here's the navigation code in the main fragment:

```
    override fun onClick(deck: SlideDeck, sourceView: View) {
        viewModel.activeDeck = deck
        val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(sourceView to "deck_details")
        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_deckListFragment2_to_deckDetailsFragment,
            null,
            null,
            extras
        )
    }
```

Here's the code to set the shared element transition in the second fragment:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val animation = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(
            android.R.transition.move
        )
        sharedElementEnterTransition = animation
        sharedElementReturnTransition = animation
        binding = FragmentDeckDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
```

Finally, back in the main fragment, I had to postpone the enter transition:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentDeckListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        postponeEnterTransition()
        binding.root.doOnPreDraw {
            startPostponedEnterTransition()
        }
        return binding.root
    }
```

I also had to make sure each element in the RecyclerView had a unique and consistent transitionName as follows:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/deckDetailsCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:transitionName="@{String.format(@string/transition_name_string, deck.id)}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> itemClickListener.onClick(deck, deckDetailsCard)}">
        ...
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Again, this all works as hoped unless I wait longer than ~5 seconds before returning to the main fragment. I've tested this on 2 emulaters (SDK 21 and 28) and a physical device (Galaxy S10E). All exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was here in the main fragment's `onViewCreated`:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val deckObserver = Observer<List<SlideDeck>> { deckList ->
            val listener: DeckListOnItemClickListener = this
            val deckListAdapter = DeckListAdapter(requireContext(), deckList,
                listener)
            deckListAdapter.dataSet = deckList
            binding.deckRecyclerView.adapter = deckListAdapter
            deckListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        viewModel.deckList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, deckObserver)
    }
```

Do you see it?

I wasn't creating an adapter for the RecyclerView until I received a change notification from the ViewModel. I think the problem was that the RecyclerView didn't have an adpater set until after the animation ran.

So I made the adapter a member of the Fragment, set the RecyclerView's `adapter` member directly in `onViewCreated`, then just updated the adapter's list when changes were observed. That seems to have fixed it.